# Build Vuejs Tailwindcss backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, vue-cli, tailwind-css

When I'm building my VueJS app using CLI and tailwindcss, my backgroundImage part of `tailwind.config.js` doesn't work.

Here's my code :

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
module.exports = {
...
   backgroundImage: {
      'arrow_back': "url('./assets/img/arrow_back.svg')"
   }
...
}
```

My class bg-arrow_back isn't created when run `npm run build`
I'm pretty sure it's because of the relative path, but when I'm reading the CLI doc, there are saying they handle it (and it does with `npm run serve`).

So if you have any idea of how to make it works ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by adding the image with v-bind. `:style="``background-image: url('${myDataImg}')``"`

Comment: So, there is no way to keep it in tailwind export ? To make it reusable ? :/

Comment: I guess there must be a way, but the way the tailwind documentation puts it, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @J.Doe What version of TailwindCSS are you using?

Comment: @juliomalves I'm on the v2.0.3, that I guess is the last one ?

Answer (score 0):

With **vitejs** and **vue3** and **tailwind 2.x** the config has to look like this:

```
theme: {
extend: {
  backgroundImage: {
    'logo-test': "url('/src/assets/logo-test.svg')"
  }
},
```

In the Html use it like this:

```
<div class="bg-logo-test"></div>
```

Comment: this does not work with Tailwind 3 and Nuxt 2.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to make this work

Comment: @Jason its config for tailwind 2.x when i wrote this tailwind 3.x wasnt out

Comment: sure, but the issue still exists.  I resorted to using `style`